# Ruby Class logger does not work

Tags: ruby

I am use logger class but I am getting error.

**Code :-**

```
class Try
  def method_missing(method_name, *args)
    logger.warn "I am try to call #{method_name} with these arguments #{args}"
    super
  end
end
Try.new.dummy(1, "my name is rosy.")
```

**Getting error:-**

```
stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

Please tell us. How to solve this problem.

Comment: My guess is that you call `dummy` which triggers `method_missing` which calls `logger` (which is **not** defined) which calls `method_missing` (for the call to `logger`) which calls `logger` ... Is this the whole source of the `Try` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are not in a rails app. Have you instantiated the `logger` instance?

```
require 'logger'

logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
logger.level = Logger::WARN

logger.warn "test"
```